# HTML 5 data attributes in HtmlHelper.xxxxxxFor overloads - object htmlAttributes / IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.SomeProperty,
        new { data_url = "http://www.google.com" }
)
```

gets rendered as

```
<input id="SomeProperty" data-url="http://www.google.com">
```

I have some custom extensions similar to this

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
{
    var htmlAttrs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

    return TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, htmlAttrs, disabled);
}

public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
{
    if (disabled)
    {
        htmlAttributes["disabled"] = true;
    }

    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
}
```

The first overload where `object htmlAttributes` is used `htmlAttributes`, invokes second overload where `htmlAttributes` gets converted to `IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes` and native TextBoxFor is invoked with `IDictionary<string, object>`. This means

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.SomeProperty,
        new { data_url = "http://www.google.com" }, model.IsSomePropertyDisabled
)
```

gets rendered as

```
<input id="SomeProperty" data_url="http://www.google.com">
```

Note **data_url** instead of **data-url**.

Essentially,

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, object htmlAttributes);
```

is smart enough to know that **data_whatever** is to be rendered as **data-whatever**, while

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

doesn't seem to apply that logic (or we can say is not smart enough). Is there a way to tell it to apply the same logic?

As a workaround, I could opt to not use these overloads when I do need the data attributes and have verbose views when the disable attribute is to be applied. Any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need the [HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) when creating `htmlAttrs` in first helper. Linked method

> Replaces underscore characters (_) with hyphens (-) in the specified
>   HTML attributes.

So, your first method should look like

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
{
    var htmlAttrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

    return TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, htmlAttrs, disabled);
}
```